# WordPress fetches the archive page instead of my custom template

Tags: page-template, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using WooCommerce and it created a page called "Shop" which I've attributed to my custom template "Store" through the "page attributes" module in the dashboard.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Store
*/
?>

        <?php get_header();?>

            <section id="content">

                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="article-wrapper">
                    <span class="top-left-corner"></span>
                    <span class="top-right-corner"></span>
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                        <span class="top-corners"></span>
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <section class="entry">
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </section>
                        <span class="bottom-corners"></span>
                    </article>
                    <span class="bottom-left-corner"></span>
                    <span class="bottom-right-corner"></span>
                </div>

                <?php endwhile; else: ?>

                <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </section>

        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

However, for some reason, WordPress keeps fetching the `archive` page instead of my custom Store page.

This is what the `body` class looks like: `<body class="archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-product logged-in woocommerce woocommerce-page infinite-scroll neverending">`

I'm aware of the issue that the slug cannot match a custom post type with the same name and I've made sure of that. I don't have any custom post types at all. I've double-checked this by changing the name of the page slug and the custom template to something random and still WordPress pulls the `archive` page.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce uses a custom post type called **product** for its product. Your shop page appears to be looking for a products archive. I can tell this because of the slug - post-type-archive-**product**

Have you tried renaming your custom shop template file `archive-product.php`? This should override the default archive template.

Comment: I just tried renaming the custom template to `archive-product.php`. Didn't work. So I tried removing the top header info (i.e. `<?php /* Template Name: Store */ ?>`). That didn't work either.

Comment: Actually, you were right. Looks like I had to override the template by creating my own `woocommerce` folder as stated in the woocommerce template: "Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php"

Answer (score -1):

Please set the template to **Default template** in the page edit.
[image]

Thanks,
sharma Chelluri

Comment: If I do this, then it just goes back to using the default template. I'm trying to use a custom template.